# CSV File Reader Module

Tags: javascript

I have two directories each has 4 sets of CSV files.
Example :

```
folder a :
       - animal.csv
       - food.csv
       - fruits.csv

folder b :
      - animal.csv
      - food.csv
      - fruits.csv
```

Now I need to merge each files like folder a animal.csv to folder b animal.csv and write it to

```
folder c :
   - animal.csv
   - food.csv
   - fruits.csv
```

This is my set of code for reading and writing a single file

```
   const folA= `folderA/animal.csv`;
    const folB = `folderB/animal.csv`;
    const final = `folderC`;
    const filename = "animal";
    const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");
    const csv = require("csv-parser");
    const file1 = [];
    const file2 = [];
    
   //Reading folder A
    fs.createReadStream(folA)
      .pipe(csv())
      .on("data", (data) => file1.push(data))
      .on("end", () => {
        //Reading folder B
        fs.createReadStream(folB)
          .pipe(csv())
          .on("data", (data) => file2.push(data))
          .on("end", () => {
            const finalData = file1.concat(file2);
            console.log(finalData);
            fastcsv
              .writeToPath(`${finalFIlePath}/${filename}.csv`, finalData)
              .on("finish", function () {
                console.log("Done");
              });
          });
      });
```

When I run this I get a merged animal.csv file in folder C. But I need to do the same to rest file in the folder in once run.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a generic function, which takes input and output file name and merges one into another and call this function 3 times since you have 3 files to read and merge, currently you are doing it for 1 file.

```
const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");
const csv = require("csv-parser");


mergeFiles ('folderA/animal.csv', 'folderB/animal.csv', 'folderC/', 'animal.csv');
mergeFiles ('folderA/food.csv', 'folderB/animal.csv', 'folderC/', 'food.csv');
mergeFiles ('folderA/fruits.csv', 'folderB/animal.csv', 'folderC/', 'fruits.csv');


function mergeFiles (folA, folB, finalFIlePath, filename) {
    //Reading folder A
    const file1 = [];
    const file2 = [];
    fs.createReadStream(folA)
        .pipe(csv())
        .on("data", (data) => file1.push(data))
        .on("end", () => {
            //Reading folder B
            fs.createReadStream(folB)
                .pipe(csv())
                .on("data", (data) => file2.push(data))
                .on("end", () => {
                    const finalData = file1.concat(file2);
                    console.log(finalData);
                    fastcsv
                        .writeToPath(`${finalFIlePath}/${filename}.csv`, finalData)
                        .on("finish", function () {
                            console.log("Done");
                        });
                });
        });
}
```

Comment: I tried to do this in single function but I can't achieve it I am new to this

Comment: I believe you don't care for order in which it gets written, updating the answer

Comment: it should read both animal file only at the same time and write once animals done next food

Comment: If it reads from both files together data assembled will be gibberish, you have to read one file at a time to make sense out of final data.

Comment: Got it instead of hardcoding three-time merge files location can we do iteration. Bcos in my case it will be 10 diff files from diff directories

Comment: yes you can iterate, create an array (or read from the database, or a file, etc) and iterate

Comment: header is not available

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to merge multiple files. Notes in the comments.

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const { parse, writeToPath } = require('fast-csv');

// The folders which we want to merge their files
const folders = [
    path.resolve('./folder_a'),
    path.resolve('./folder_b'),
];

// The destination folder
const finalFolder = path.resolve('./folder_c');

// Create the destination if it is not there
if (!fs.existsSync(finalFolder)) fs.mkdirSync(finalFolder);

// Function to return a file's contents
const parseFile = async (file, folder) => {
    
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        
        const contents = [];

        fs.createReadStream(`${folder}/${file}`)
            .pipe(parse())
            .on('data', (data) => {
                contents.push(data);
            })
            .once('end', () => {

                resolve({
                    file,
                    header: contents[0],
                    contents: contents.slice(1),
                });
            });
    });
};

const main = async () => {
    
    const data = {};

    for (const folder of folders) {

        // Get all the filenames the folder contains
        const files = fs.readdirSync(folder);
        
        // Parse the contents of the folder's files
        const contents = await Promise.all(
            files.map((file) => parseFile(file, folder))
        );

        // Keep for each file its name, header and contents
        for (const content of contents) {

            data[content.file] = data[content.file] || { header: content.header };

            data[content.file].contents = (data[content.file].contents || []).concat(content.contents);
        }
    }

    for (const [filename, { header, contents }] of Object.entries(data)) {

        // Wait for each write operation to finish
        await new Promise((resolve) => {

            writeToPath(`${finalFolder}/${filename}`, [header, ...contents]).once('finish', resolve);
        });
    }
};

main();
```